# Visual studio 2013 error code when opening connection to database

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, database-connection

Here is my code: http://imgur.com/OmumQq3

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Not a valid file name.

So the problem, visual studio won't allow me to open my connection to my database.

Comment: First of all: you can and should post your code here rather than a link to an image that must be zoomed. Then: those tip brackets in your path `<` must go. Third: use a proper path with backslashes, escaped like this: `C:\\Users\\...`

Comment: Sorry I am new here but I will do that the next time! But thanks a lot man that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Connection string is missing Integrated Security, Try adding this to the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use a proper path to your db in your connection string, e.g.:

```
var connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\[username]\\Documents\\test.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
```